# is windows 6 based dll runnable partially on windows 5?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

you got some third party dll which relays on winapi

winapi has some versions and some functions were added say in win 6 win 7 etc

I'm not sure one thing, say if this third party dll in generall relays on windows 6 I mean it uses a lot of functions from winapi 5 but only one or two from winapi 6

say you then want to use this third party dll on windows 5 - say you only call a subset of its functionality that just doesn't call this winapi 6 functions

is it generally possible? (or just it is impossible form some reason? if no what exactly is that reason?

for example, this third party dll has this win6 functions listed in imports but I also belive some functions you call just don't use it and I'm not sure if it is possible to use limited functionality of this dll on win5 too)

thnx for clarification if someone knows

Comment: @lurker: Why not? It will load the module, if it can resolve the load-time dynamic link dependencies.

Comment: *that just dont calls thise winapi 6 functions* - if dll *import* some api which not exist in old windows version - this dll fail to load. dont call this api not help. dll must initially not import not existing api. solution can be say use delayimport

Comment: The traditional way to solve this is to call all Windows 5 functions by name, but call any Windows 6 functions (conditionally) via `LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAddress`.  That way the app will load on Windows 5 because it is not directly referencing any Windows 6 API's, and that's what the loader cares about.

Comment: RbMm are you sure? im asking ocz i dont know - is that dll checked against the all imported symbols when being loaded to ram? isnt there any delay system of that checks involved or something like this?

Comment: Paul Sanders the problem is im not the author of this third party dll... i would just liek to use it on windows 5 in a 'partial' way... i mean assuming thet i would only use some calls to it that dont call to win6 functions ;c i understand hovever you say it will not work (though theoretically maybe it in theory could work, im not sure hovever if in fact it could work even in theory)

Comment: If the DLL contains direct references to Windows 6 functions then it won't load on Windows 5, sorry.  Contact your software vendor.

Answer (score 2):

If the DLL is implicitly linked to DLLs or functions that are not present in the prevailing system, then the load will fail. It doesn't matter tl whether or not you actually call the functions that are not present, implicitly linked dependencies are resolved at load time.

Comment: Even if the module uses implicit linking, it could still opt to mark the dependencies as `/DELAYLOAD`, handing control back to a process to deal with unresolved externals. Depending on the dependencies, this could open an opportunity to gracefully handle up-level dependencies. But the question is way too incomplete to make that call.

Comment: IInspectable if so im still confused... imagine such situation, i say this thirdparty library is some support library that is designed towork with windows 6 or above... i would like to use it on windows 5... is there any chance i could be able to do that? make that work on windows 5?

Comment: you may probably assume as windows 6 added onlu some minof functions, like few extended versions of some not much important functions, the majority of functions is the same... still i wonder if i would mark delayload that win6 import in this third party dll i could use it or no (and delay the message box "symbol not found" to a moment when i wopuld call in runtime something that actually calls it)

Comment: i would need to craft it myself on win10 then try it on win5 (xp) i could do it in fact but its to much effort as for now... thiose answers i see here i must say are abourt the topic bot not much conclusive

Comment: You don't need to craft anything. You just need to try to load the dll on xp. If it fails then it's game over. Also, I think my answer is on topic but perhaps you don't understand the issues well enough yet.